# how to Join MediaStore.Audio.Media

Tags: android, mediastore

Hi im using merge cursor to show the data result in my list view, i added an indexer and all its working fine but i noticed the a-z its ok show me the External Data, after that again a-z but now internal data, so my index "works" but not as i wish, i know mergecursor cant be sorted so im wondering can i do a rawquery? to join
 MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_UR ?? and how? i want to join and then sort by Song ASC. or MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER 
or how i can convert an array list or other collection to cursor?

Current Code:

```
private Cursor getInternalAudioCursor(String selection,
    String[] selectionArgs) {
return this.getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        INTERNAL_COLUMNS,
        selection,
        selectionArgs,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

}

```
private Cursor getExternalAudioCursor(String selection,
    String[] selectionArgs) {
return this.getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        EXTERNAL_COLUMNS,
        selection,
        selectionArgs,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

}

```
Cursor c = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[] {
        getExternalAudioCursor(selection, argsArray),
        getInternalAudioCursor(selection, argsArray)});
startManagingCursor(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do a `rawQuery` because

- `MediaStore` (actually `MediaProvider`) is a `ContentProvider`, not an `SQLiteDatabase` (it is under that abstraction layer though) - it does not provide those SQLite operations intentionally since you could have other things backing a ContentProvider than an SQLite database.
- `internal` and `external` are separate database files & accessed separately. You can't build queries that refer to another file (unless you attach them which you can't since you don't have access to that low level)

You could build a [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) in which you put the data of both source Cursors in a sorted order.